# Hibernate JPA constraint violation and Transaction already active

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a table with the field 'nom' with the unique constraint and when I test to insert a value of this field that already exists in the table the **org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException** is thrown. Then after all my persisting I get a **Transaction already active** Exception.

this is my persisting method in a Dao class

```
public void persist(E entity) throws Exception {
EntityTransaction tr=entityManager.getTransaction() ;
tr.begin();
entityManager.persist(entity);
tr.commit();
 }
```

and here the code where I catch the exception

```
try {

        rd.persist(r);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How Can I solve this Transaction problem  ?

Comment: Avoid using programmatic transactions. Use declarative transactions instead.

Comment: where should I put the @transactional annotation ?

Comment: The `@Transactional` annotation can be placed on your service class or it can also be used on method level overriding the class level annotation depending upon the requirements.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @macias you could see the edit please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of explicitly opening the transaction you could allow the framework to handle the transaction (like in spring you can use the @transactional). But if not it looks like the code has a begin and a commit in case it is successful, try adding a tr.rollback() in the persist method using a finally (or you could even check whether the transaction is still active using the tr.isActive() method.

Comment: the error is caused by what ? is the transaction doesn't finish ?

Comment: yes, in case of error the tr.commit() is skipped, so if you put tr.rollback() in catch block it would probably solve the error.

Comment: `try {

    if(!tr.isActive())
     tr.begin();
     entityManager.persist(entity);
      tr.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
      tr.rollback();
}`

Comment: ganaraj,@mecias this code very well thx ,but is there other way ,because I don't think it's the best way ;)

Comment: Instead of a rollback you could as well commit if you want. One more option you could try is to check whether the transaction is active in your catch block outside the persist method. try { rd.persist(r); } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); EntityTransaction tr=entityManager.getTransaction() ; if(tr.isActive()) ( //either commit or rollback here)}

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to do anything with Transaction, because it is handled by Spring.

I met "Transaction already active". Though I think what caused it is different with your problem, I think my answer should help someone.

For example:

```
// Transaction handled by Spring
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
...
return;

------------------------------------------------------------

// Transaction handled by yourself
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transcation tr = session.beginTransaction();
...
tr.commit();
session.close();
return;
```